# Copy file from terminal and paste in GUI and vice versa

Tags: command-line, files, gui, copy, paste

Is there a way to copy a file with a terminal command and then paste it via the GUI somewhere? I just wondered that. I never thought of this so far, but sometimes that would be really handy. Would work like this:

```
$ copytogui <some file>
```

- open some directory `d` in file browser
- press `ctrl-v`
- `<some file>` has been copied to `d`

And vice versa for copying from a GUI window to the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you are looking for is a **clipboard manager** capable of "clipping" files of any type (as opposed to just un-formatted text), and you want this software to have a command-line interface, as well as the ability to use keyboard shortcuts to interact with GUI applications like your file manager.

I am not aware of any software *in official* Ubuntu repositories that would meet all of these qualifications.

But there does appear to be at least one open source (*GPLv3*) project that could meet your needs:

**[CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/)**

**App Description**:

*CopyQ monitors system clipboard and saves its content in customized tabs. Saved clipboard can be later copied and pasted directly into any application.*

**Features Include**:

- Store text, HTML, images or any other custom formats
- Advanced command-line interface and scripting
- System-wide shortcuts with customizable commands
- Paste items with shortcut or from tray or main window

There are installation paths for Ubuntu via PPA and there is also a "[flatpak](https://www.flatpak.org/)" under "**com.github.hluk.copyq**"

Since this is not in Ubuntu's repositories, that means that the Ubuntu community does not maintain this software nor does the Ubuntu community audit the software for bugs or vulnerabilities.  I personally can not vouch for it either, since I have not used it.  However, the project is fairly active on [github](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) and has [extensive documentation](https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as well as 145 contributors as of the authoring of this answer.  These are *generally* good signs that an application is safe to use.